# App not starting after porting project from ObjC to Swift

Tags: ios, swift

I've ported a empty project from ObjC to Swift (I know I could have started with swift, but for the sake of this question, let's assume this is not an option)

I've removed ObjC classes, including the `main` file, and replaced them by a simple `AppDelegate.swift` and `ViewController.swift`:

AppDelegate.swift:

```
import UIKit

@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

    func application(
        _ application: UIApplication,
        didFinishLaunchingWithOptions
        launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey : Any]? = nil) -> Bool {
        return true
    }
}
```

ViewController.swift:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    print("ViewController")
  }
}
```

and I made sure my initial storyboard uses a UIViewController of type ViewController.

Things are compiling fine but the app is not starting, the AppDelegate didFinishLaunchingWithOptions function is not called, and no view is visible. I guess I somehow need to tell Xcode that the new entry point is `AppDelegate.swift`, which I hoped `@UIApplicationMain` was doing.

For more context I'm setting a pod that needs to be written in objective C but I want the demo app to be in swift. I could not find an option to do so automatically through cocoapods, so I set everything to objective C and I'm trying to move the demo app to swift. I didn't change any build setting manually.

Comment: Have you made any changes in build settings?

Comment: nop, unless what gets autogenerated by the addition/removal of files.

Comment: To run your code your app should have Swift Compiler. check in build settings

Comment: I think it have much changes beside the files, build settings matters, but it's totally fine to use obj-c and swift in each other pj, so I think u can create obj-c project and use all swift also fine

Comment: @MaheshNarla which build settings? I've a bunch of settings related to swift compilation that looks fine (ie like in a working swift project)

Comment: Did you create an iOS target?

Comment: @Tj3n I know I can use swift with objc and the other way around. My issue is that nothing is running atm

Comment: Are you sure the old `main` is not there? Even in an unused file?

Comment: Yes I removed the main. If the main was there, Xcode cannot compile since there'd be two main files (one other generated by @UIApplicationMain)

Comment: @Guig It's worked for me with out errors. . I did the same, deleted AppDelegate.h , AppDelegate.m and ViewController.h,ViewController.m and main . . created new AppDelegate.swift and ViewController.swift files, while creating swift file it asks to generate BridgingHeader File.

Comment: Did you had to add a window property to the app delegate, and set it's root view controller? I think I missed that (see my answer)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up solving the issue with cleaning the build and adding a window attribute to the app delegate...

The AppDelegate needs to have a `var window: UIWindow?` property. This was present in the Objective C version and I stupidly forgot to put it in the swift version. Somehow after cleaning the build folder, Xcode started to complain of the absence of such property and I put it back in.

This `window` property should be set when launching, as well as its root view controller that should be the one from the storyboard. This while part was not in the Objective C version that was working fine which was sinply:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    return YES;
}
```

So I now have:

```
// AppDelegate.swift
import UIKit

@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {
  var window: UIWindow?

  func application(
    _ application: UIApplication,
    didFinishLaunchingWithOptions
    launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey : Any]? = nil) -> Bool {

    window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
    window?.rootViewController = UIStoryboard.init(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateInitialViewController()
    window?.makeKeyAndVisible()

    return true
  }
}
```

and that worked